# Excel Sheet Codenames in Formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a formula in VBA to match some rows. Currently I have something like:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=INDEX('Report 2'!C[4],MATCH(Report!RC[2],'Report 2'!C[8],0))"
```

Where the sheet code name for Report is Sheet1 and sheet code name for Report 2 is Sheet2. So I would like to change the above code to something like:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=INDEX(Sheet2!C[4],MATCH(Sheet1!RC[2],Sheet2!C[8],0))"
```

Is this possible? It tried searching but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "code name"? is it a variable holding the real name of your sheet?

Comment: Sheet code name which is internally available in Excel VBA code. [See this](http://www.excel-it.com/SheetName.htm)

Comment: then it is just a matter of concatenating the string that builds the formula, as John Bustos proposes in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... This should do it:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('" & Sheet2.Name & "'!C[4],MATCH(" & Sheet1.Name & "!RC[2],'" & Sheet2.Name & "'!C[8],0))"
```