# Excel Reference External Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

An excel question for you gurus. I've tried searching high and low and haven't come up with an effective solution.

I'm trying to create a formula that will lookup a value in an external sheet. I'm using the SUMPRODUCT formula and it works perfectly. Formula is below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('File\Path\[file.xlsx]SheetName!$D$1:$D$1000=$B3), --('File\Path\[file.xlsx]SheetName'!$O$1:$O$1000=$A3), 'File\Path\[file.xlsx]SheetName'!$Q$1:$Q$1000)
```

The issue I'm running into, however, is that the source file is updated every day. Although the workbook name stays the same, the sheet name changes. A random string gets assigned to the source sheet name each time it is updated. As such `SheetName` becomes `SheetName ase341`.

Is there a way to have the formula read the external sheet number instead of the name? I want the formula to update regardless of the sheet name. If there's no way to read the sheet position is there a way to change the sheet name via a formula in an external workbook?

---

#### Usage Example

I have a workbook (analysis) and it pulls data from another workbook (source). Source is updated every day with new data. The data in Source is updated by downloading a report from the internet and saving over the old source file. As such, the file name stays the same but whatever is inside the file is always different (including the sheet name). There is always only ever one sheet in the Source with the same number of columns, always in the same position.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428189/excel-sheet-codenames-in-formula-vba might help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really neat way to refer to a block of cells in an external workbook in which the sheetname or even the block address may vary. Say we have:

```
=SUM('C:\Users\James\Desktop\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$9)
```

however the sheetname may vary.  First assign a *Defined Name* to the block in *Book1* (say *XXX*)

Then we can use:

```
=SUM('C:\Users\James\Desktop\Book1.xlsx'!XXX)
```

It does not matter if the sheetname changes, the *Defined Name* will change with it!

Comment: Thanks for this! However, the issue I run into is that a new file is saved over the old one when updating the content. As such, any predefined _anything_ will be erased upon update. This is why I wanted to pull the location externally so that whoever is using this workbook will not have to manually open the source sheet every day and rename it.

Comment: @LahiruTM:  If it is a brand new file with the same name, how do YOU *(the human)* know which sheet has the proper data???

Comment: @GarysStudent - Apologies if this is confusing. I have a workbook (analysis) and it pulls data from another workbook (source). Source is updated every day with new data. The data is updated is by downloading a report from the internet and saving over the old source file. As such, the file name stays the same but whatever is inside the file is always different (including the sheet name). However, there is always only ever one sheet in the Source with the same number of columns, always in the same position.

Comment: @LahiruTM:  You have made the problem completely clear!  The only solution I can think of is to use a **VBA** macro to: **1** open the source workbook **2** retrieve the sheetname **3** modify the formula in the analysis workbook.............are you familiar with macros??

Comment: @GarysStudent - I'm just starting to learn about them. I'll try and give it a go.

Comment: Is there anything about the sheet name in the workbook that a) is always the same/present to that sheet (eg. begins with or contains the phrase ' xyz' or Sheet 1, etc...) and b) is unique to that sheet (ie no other sheets begin or contain 'xyz'?  When you say the "one sheet in Source" is always in the same position, do you mean the same tab (1st, 5th, 22nd, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue would be most efficiently solved with VBA, but if you're just getting started this might not be the best route.

You can get the sheetname or filename with just a formula, though:

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/return-sheet-name.htm